# How to Add search Bar in Django raw_id_fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So here is the problem I a facing, I have multiple apps in one app have all the contact info of my users and other apps are my departements where I will register the users form contact app.

I used raw_id_fields to extend thier info and achieve what I want

this is the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWIZY.png)
When i click on that maginyfing Glass it takes me to contacts but it has no search bar
[no search bar in raw_id_fields}(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywp0e.png)

How to do i add the bar in it
This is my code

```
class PersonRegistrationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('person_role', 'contact')
    search_fields = ('contact__name', 'contact__phone_number', 'contact__email', 'contact__date_of_birth', 'contact__cnic')
    raw_id_fields = ('contact',)


admin.site.register(PersonRegistration, PersonRegistrationAdmin)
```

I tried a few ways but looks like I could not achieve what I want

Comment: Shouldn't that be `autocomplete_fields = ('contact',)`?

Comment: When you use that magnifying glass icon you get a popup of the `contact` admin, so I believe you need to set `search_fields` on that.

Comment: Yup but I dont not know how to add  'search_fields' on that

Answer (score 0):

I Figured it out,
If you wanna add search bar in `raw_id_fields` then add `search_fields` on the model you are calling bcz basically it is pop up of your your Model.